# functools stops working when switch to Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, eclipse, functools

We have migrated our Django project code base from Python 2.7 to 3.6 and suddenly what used to work stopped.  Specifically, this:

```
map(functools.partial(self._assocUser, user=user), persistedGroupIds)
```

needed to be replaced with:

```
 for group_id in persistedGroupIds:
      self._assocUser(group_id, user)
```

and this:

```
    persistedGroupIds = map(functools.partial(self._persistGroup, grp_mappings=attrAll.entitlements), saml_authorization_attributes)
```

needed to go to:

```
     persistedGroupIds = []
     for idp_group_name in saml_authorization_attributes:
         persistedGroupIds.append(self._persistGroup(idp_group_name, attrAll.entitlements))
```

before the old functionality reappeared.  Python 3's `functools` don't seem to work.

Here's the full listing of the code that works fine under Python 2:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
import functools
from mappings import SAMLAttributesConfig
from django.conf import settings
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class SAMLServiceProviderBackend(object):

    empty_entitlements_message="IdP supplied incorrect authorization entitlements.  Please contact their support."

    def _assocUser(self, group_id, user):

        group = Group.objects.get(id=group_id)
        group.user_set.add(user)

        return None


    def _persistGroup(self,idp_group_name, grp_mappings):

        group_name = grp_mappings[idp_group_name]

        try:
            group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
        except Group.DoesNotExist:
            group = Group(name=group_name)
            group.save()

        return group.id

    def _extract_grp_entitlements(self,saml_authentication_attributes,groups):
        result = []
        input_length = len(saml_authentication_attributes[groups])
        if input_length == 0:
            log.error(self.empty_entitlements_message)
            raise RuntimeError(self.empty_entitlements_message)
        if input_length == 1:
            result = [t.strip() for t in saml_authentication_attributes[groups][0].split(',')] 
        elif input_length:
            result = saml_authentication_attributes[groups]
        return result
#         return [t.strip() for t in saml_authentication_attributes[groups][0].split(',')] \
#             if len(saml_authentication_attributes[groups]) == 1\
#             else saml_authentication_attributes[groups]


    def authenticate(self, saml_authentication=None):
        if not saml_authentication:  # Using another authentication method
            return None

        attrAll = SAMLAttributesConfig(mappings_file_name=settings.AUTH_MAPPINGS_FILE).get_config()
        groups = attrAll.entitlements.containerName

        if saml_authentication.is_authenticated():

            saml_authentication_attributes = saml_authentication.get_attributes()
            saml_authorization_attributes = self._extract_grp_entitlements(saml_authentication_attributes,groups)          
            persistedGroupIds = map(functools.partial(self._persistGroup, grp_mappings=attrAll.entitlements), saml_authorization_attributes)  

            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=saml_authentication.get_nameid())
            except User.DoesNotExist:

                user = User(username=saml_authentication.get_nameid())
                user.set_unusable_password()
                try:
                    user.first_name = saml_authentication_attributes['samlNameId'][0]
                except KeyError:
                    pass
                try:
                    setattr(user, "first_name", saml_authentication_attributes[attrAll.subject.first_name][0])

                except KeyError:
                    pass 

                #user.last_name = attributes['Last name'][0]
                user.save()
                map(functools.partial(self._assocUser, user=user), persistedGroupIds)
                user.save()
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

The above code no longer works under Python 3 environment and only starts working to something like this, with a `functools.partial()` calls spelled out in a `for` loop:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
import functools
from .mappings import SAMLAttributesConfig
from django.conf import settings
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class SAMLServiceProviderBackend(object):

    empty_entitlements_message="IdP supplied incorrect authorization entitlements.  Please contact their support."

    def _assocUser(self, group_id, user):

        group = Group.objects.get(id=group_id)
        group.user_set.add(user)

        return None


    def _persistGroup(self,idp_group_name, grp_mappings):

        group_name = grp_mappings[idp_group_name]

        try:
            group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
        except Group.DoesNotExist:
            group = Group(name=group_name)
            group.save()

        return group.id

    def _extract_grp_entitlements(self,saml_authentication_attributes,groups):
        result = []
        input_length = len(saml_authentication_attributes[groups])
        if input_length == 0:
            log.error(self.empty_entitlements_message)
            raise RuntimeError(self.empty_entitlements_message)
        if input_length == 1:
            result = [t.strip() for t in saml_authentication_attributes[groups][0].split(',')] 
        elif input_length:
            result = saml_authentication_attributes[groups]
        return result
#         return [t.strip() for t in saml_authentication_attributes[groups][0].split(',')] \
#             if len(saml_authentication_attributes[groups]) == 1\
#             else saml_authentication_attributes[groups]


    def authenticate(self, saml_authentication=None):
        if not saml_authentication:  # Using another authentication method
            return None

        attrAll = SAMLAttributesConfig(mappings_file_name=settings.AUTH_MAPPINGS_FILE).get_config()
        groups = attrAll.entitlements.containerName

        if saml_authentication.is_authenticated():

            saml_authentication_attributes = saml_authentication.get_attributes()
            saml_authorization_attributes = self._extract_grp_entitlements(saml_authentication_attributes,groups)          
            persistedGroupIds = map(functools.partial(self._persistGroup, grp_mappings=attrAll.entitlements), saml_authorization_attributes)  

            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=saml_authentication.get_nameid())
            except User.DoesNotExist:

                user = User(username=saml_authentication.get_nameid())
                user.set_unusable_password()
                try:
                    user.first_name = saml_authentication_attributes['samlNameId'][0]
                except KeyError:
                    pass
                try:
                    setattr(user, "first_name", saml_authentication_attributes[attrAll.subject.first_name][0])

                except KeyError:
                    pass 

                #user.last_name = attributes['Last name'][0]
                user.save()
                for group_id in persistedGroupIds:
                    self._assocUser(user = user, group_id = group_id)
                # map(functools.partial(self._assocUser, user=user), persistedGroupIds)
                user.save()
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

What can be wrong?

I'm using PyDev plugin in Eclipse.  Here's how my Python interpreter is configured there:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Here's Eclipse's .pydevproject file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?eclipse-pydev version="1.0"?><pydev_project>



    <pydev_property name="org.python.pydev.PYTHON_PROJECT_INTERPRETER">venv3.6</pydev_property>



    <pydev_property name="org.python.pydev.PYTHON_PROJECT_VERSION">python interpreter</pydev_property>



    <pydev_variables_property name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_VARIABLE_SUBSTITUTION">

        <key>DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE</key>

        <value>reporting.settings</value>

        <key>DJANGO_MANAGE_LOCATION</key>

        <value>./manage.py</value>

        <key>SAML_PLUGIN</key>

        <value>/Users/sl/abc/venv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onelogin/saml2</value>

        <key>PY</key>

        <value>36</value>

    </pydev_variables_property>



    <pydev_pathproperty name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_SOURCE_PATH">



        <path>/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}</path>



    </pydev_pathproperty>



    <pydev_pathproperty name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_EXTERNAL_SOURCE_PATH">

        <path>${SAML_PLUGIN}</path>

    </pydev_pathproperty>


</pydev_project>
```

Comment: Has there been an error or why do you state it doesn't work?

Comment: No, there's no error per say, but the expected functionality is not present, the tests start breaking, etc.  In other words, only the consequences of the change are apparent, there is no Python error that manifests itself.  Maybe it's `functools` or maybe it's `map` that's not working, I'm not seeing the breakpoint being hit inside the enclosed functions.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, the map function [returns an iterator instead of a list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists).

This means that if you call `map` on a collection, the effects of the call are not materialised until you iterate over the resulting iterator.

Consider this class:

```
>>> class C:
...     def __init__(self, x):
...         self.x = x
...     def double(self):
...         self.x *= 2
...     def __repr__(self):                                                                                             
...         return '<C:{}>'.format(self.x)
...
```

Let's make a list of instances:

```
>>> cs = [C(x) for x in range(1, 4)]
>>> cs
[<C:1>, <C:2>, <C:3>]
```

Now use `map` to call each instance's `double` method:

```
>>> res = map(C.double, cs)
```

Note the result is not a list:

```
>>> res
<map object at 0x7ff276350470>
```

And the instances have not changed:

```
>>> cs
[<C:1>, <C:2>, <C:3>]
```

if we call next on the iterator, the instances are updated in turn.

```
>>> next(res)
>>> cs
[<C:2>, <C:2>, <C:3>]
>>> next(res)
>>> cs
[<C:2>, <C:4>, <C:3>]
>>> next(res)
>>> cs
[<C:2>, <C:4>, <C:6>]
```

In the code samples that you have provided, the result of calling `map` is not assigned to a variable, so `map` is being used for its side effects rather than its output.  In Python 3  the correct way to do this is to loop over the iterable and call the function on each element:

```
>>> for c in cs:
        c.double()
```

As the linked doc puts it:

> Particularly tricky is `map()` invoked for the side effects of the function; the correct transformation is to use a regular for loop (since creating a list would just be wasteful).

Comment: So they effectively discourage using `map()` for side effects in this way, it seems?  Is there a replacement to it (in `functools`  or somewhere else) which returns the list where one wouldn't need to wrap it in a list or do some other acrobatics to materialize the list (say, for bounded collection of iterables)?

Comment: Not that I know of - you either need to call `list(map(func, objs))` if you want to materialize the result or use a `for` loop if you just want side-effects.